# SqLite Multicore Processing

Tags: sqlite, processing, multicore

How do you configure SqLite 3 to process a single query using more than 1 core of a CPU ?

Answer (score 4):

Since version 3.8.7, SQLite can use multiple threads for parallel sorting of large data sets.

Answer (score 2):

sqlite3 itself does not do that.

However, I have a project called [multicoresql](http://github.com/drpaulbrewer/multicoresql) on github that has utility programs and a C library for spreading sql queries onto multiple cores.

It uses sharding so you have to break your large database or datafile into multiple sqlite3 database files. A single SQL query must be written as two SQL queries, a map query that first runs on all the shards, and a reduce query to determine the result from the collected output from all the shards running the map query.