# parallel aggregation functions

Tags: sqlite

Can some aggregate functions like count() or sum() work in parallel on multi-core machines with SQLite[34]?

I have massive number of rows and I need counting/summing some cols, and I wonder if this can be done in parallel.

Comment: But keep in mind that these operations are probably I/O-constrained anyway.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25265502/sqlite-multicore-processing

Comment: Along with massive rows, we have a high number of core (64) and gigantic physmem, and then potentially the table incore (page cache). So at some point counting() summing() become cpu bound on single threaded DB engine.

Answer (score 2):

As of version 3.9, the only operation that SQLite can execute on multiple cores is sorting.

Comment: And would it be reasonable to think about couting/summing too, does the splitting technic I guess used in the sorted be re-usable on some ways?

Comment: Forgot to add that the table I am talking about are 'frozen' no more write activity to it, etc, only read (dunno if it helps to implement a paracount()